# Getting warning You have not yet selected a version of Spinnaker to deploy

Tags: spinnaker-halyard

I'm trying out Spinnaker and did a fresh Halyard installation. Now when I'm running any Hal commands, I'm getting the following warning.

> WARNING You have not yet selected a version of Spinnaker to
>     deploy.

How to avoid getting this warning? Quick Googling didn't land me on any Spinnaker documentation
pointing to this warning.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Halyard needs a Spinnaker version to picked for deploying. This can be done with the following commands,

1. List down the available Spinnaker versions

   ```
   hal version list
   ```
2. Pick your preferred version

   ```
   hal config version edit --version yourPrefferedVersion
   ```

   More on this can be found on https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/deploy/#pick-a-version